# JQuery - Set "open" attribute without a value

Tags: html, jquery, attr, prop

[web.dev](https://web.dev)'s mobile nav menu sets an attribute of `open` without a value

```
<web-navigation-drawer type="standard" animating="" open="">
```

How can I achieve this?

```
something.attr('open')
something.attr('open', '')
```

Both produce `open="open"`

`.prop()` doesn't seem to work either.

Any thoughts on how they're doing this?

*(Note: `open="open"` is perfectly fine, I just think `open` is cleaner - and clearly so do Google)*

Thanks in advance, Mr J.

Comment: Don't worry about the cleanliness of HTML markup - it's only the *source* code that needs to be clean (for developers to be able to analyze and work with)

Comment: Not sure why this has been marked as [duplicate], the answers within the other questions don't work in this scenario (and were the first places I looked). Regardless of html cleanliness, it would be nice to find out how the Google devs achieved this.